# How to include conio.h in cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin, getch

I want use getch(); in cygwin.
So i search the way,add the code "conio.h".

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* reads from keypress, doesn't echo */
int getch(void)
{
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
    return ch;
}

/* reads from keypress, echoes */
int getche(void)
{
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
    return ch;
}
```

After save this code "conio.h",i can't use getch();.
the error message is
 fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
                   ^
compilation terminated.

How to solve it?

Comment: You can find multiple solutions here:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126842/conio-h-file-missing-error

Answer (score 0):

any other file that wants to use the functions in your conio.c file (which should be the appropriate file name extension for the file you posted) needs to have prototypes for those functions.

Specifically you need a second file conio.h  that looks like;

```
#ifndef CONIO_H
#define CONIO_H

int getch( void );
int getche( void );

#endif // CONIO_H
```

The conio.h file needs to be #include "conio.h" in any file that wants to use those functions

Comment: Naturally, the compiler needs to be applied to the conio.c and your file and the linker needs to include both conio.o and yourfile.o,  for the conio.h file to be found during the compile step, the compiler needs to know the path to the conio.h file.  (in gcc use -IpathToHeaderFile)